# NSDictionary objectForkey and accessing the key directly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a simple question about accessing different ways of accessing values stored in  NSDictionary. so if i have a dictionary like

```
NSDictionary *dict =@{@"Mammal" : @"Cow", @"Bird" : @"Eagle"};
```

Now what is the difference if i access the elements like `dict[@"Mammal"]` and `[dict objectForKey:@"Mammal"]` what if there is no object with key `@"Mammal"` in this case. Does it crash with `dict[@"Mammal"]` or `dict[@"Mammal"]` calls `[dict objectForKey:@"Mammal"]` under the hood.

Is it the similar case with `NSArray`, `NSMutableArray` & `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: `NSDictionary` will return null in that case

Comment: If you use `NSArray` with invalid index, it'll crash with array index out of bounds exception

Comment: Why don't you just try? It doesn't take long.

Comment: What about reading the doc of the methods of `objectForKey:`? What about trying?

Comment: Which documentation did you read, and what did you find that you didn't understand?

Comment: My question was actually that Do dict[@"Mammal"] calls [dict objectForKey:@"Mammal"] under the hood or not....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dict[@"Mammal"]` actually calls `- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key`under the hood.

The behaviour is the same as calling `[dict objectForKey:@"Mammal"]` according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKeyedSubscript:):

> **Return Value**
>
> The value associated with *aKey*, or nil if no value is associated with aKey.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method behaves the same as *objectForKey:*.